# use of could / would - correct the sentence - I like that piece of furniture. I wish it could fit in my apartment

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, modal-verbs, grammaticality-in-context, could-modal

> I like that piece of furniture. I wish it could fit in my apartment.
>
> **Options: -**
>
> 1. was able to fit
> 2. might
> 3. would

**My answer:** I like that piece of furniture. I wish it **would** fit in my apartment.

**Correct answer:** I like that piece of furniture. I wish it **was able to** fit in my apartment.

**My doubt** - What is the difference? The way I see it - I feel both are correct!

**use of would & could:** both are done to report a past conversation. The way I see it, the entire sentence was in the past and I feel "both" are correct.

I don't understand is how can "would" be incorrect here. And even if it is incorrect, isn't "could" already the correct use then?

How are "would" & "could" both incorrect here?

**EDIT -**

I checked on a few "grammar checking" websites - the use of both could & would don't show any errors. Though, use of "was able to" was correctly shown as -

"I like that piece of furniture. I wish it was able to fit **into** my apartment"

Comment: "was able" is wrong. You cannot refer to a thing being able/unable to do something.

Comment: To confirm what I just told you, see there is a comment in that quiz that says: Several of your answers are incorrect."My mother well speaks English": "We worked hardly" and **saying a couch was able to fit in a space indicates that the couch is alive.**

Comment: @Gustavson and what would be the correct usage then - would or could?

Comment: I disagree with Gustavson's claim about "able" implying life/agency. "Was able to fit" seems like the correct answer to me, assuming you are looking to replace "could" from the original sentence.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica and why is that? Why can we replace "could" with "was able to fit" and not with "would". That is my original question

Comment: I also disagree that you cannot use *was able*. All three sentences are grammatical and meaningful; none of them are wrong.

Comment: i think would is correct. Here it is used in subjunctive sense, not in past tense.